# The number is getting concatinated instead of adding

Tags: python

I am trying to build a utility that replaces a perticulor sequence from a file. but instead of adding its concatenating. Please Help.

**new.txt contains**

Test1 
Test2 
Test3 
... 
... 
Test53

**expected Output**

PONUM0001001
PONUM0001002
PONUM0001003
...
...
PONUM0001010
PONUM0001011
PONUM0001012
...
...
PONUM0001053

**I am getting**

PONUM0001001
PONUM0001002
PONUM0001003
...
...
PONUM00010010 // extra Zero here, its concatenating 
PONUM00010011
PONUM00010012
...
...
PONUM00010053

**Code is**

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)

try:
    os.mkdir(path + "\\order")
except :
    pass

with open(path + "\\new.txt", "r") as rf:
    fileContent = rf.read()

k = 1000
for i in range(1,54):
    num = "Test" + str(i)
    PONumber = "PONUM000" + str(k + int(i))
    print(PONumber)
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(num,PONumber)
    print(PONumber)

with open(path + "\\order\\sample.txt","w") as wf:
    wf.write(fileContent)
    
input("enter any key")
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you are getting the expected output so, what is the issue? Probably you need to edit the question and correct the input/expected/current outputs.

Comment: extra zero after i crosses 9, I will add this comment in the question

Comment: @sachin my mistake, didnt spot that difference, you're correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing `Test + str(i)` in the file with the new value.

Suppose this is `Test5`

It will replace `Test5` in `Test53`, resulting in  `PONUM00010053`

You will probably want to replace only `Test5` and not also `Test50`, `Test51` etc., so consider replacing only once with `replace(num, PONumber, 1)` instead of `replace(num, PONumber)`.

Comment: thanks you found it right, I will do the changes

Comment: Doing a string replace on the entire file contents is not a great solution in general.  I would have a function that processes and replaces each line individually.  That way you only need to scan the file contents once instead of N times, and you won't get any "interference" from similar-looking lines like this.

Comment: How can we do if I have random repetition of Test1 to Test53, i.e I don't know how many times Test1 will come in that file

Comment: There is many ways. You could also test on the new line coming after the word and replace with a new new line, e.g. `replace("Test5\n", "PONUM0001005\n")`. Or you could make it more robust by reading individual lines with e.g. readlines() or file_content.split('\n') and then checking against full lines.

Comment: Another option is to first replace the largest number and work towards lower numbers, since larger numbers will never be part of smaller numbers.